# How to overcome java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I map a data taken from a text file. The text file is supposed to have 5 columns. e.g.

```
29000000    1   0   2013    1   single-sex
29000000    1   0   2013    1   education
29000000    1   0   2013    1   and
29000000    1   0   2013    1   the
29000000    1   0   2013    1   brain
```

In my process I need only those values appearing on the 0th and 5th columns. So to get those I wrote the following:

```
val emp = 
  sc.textFile("\\.txt")
    .map{line => val s = line.split("\t"); (s(5),s(0))}
```

However, it is possible that sometimes 5th column does not exist for some rows and I get

> 15/10/12 17:19:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 27.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 27) on executor localhost: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (5)

So on my mapping how should I write a if condition if s(5) exists or not?

Comment: What does the business logic of your application require you to do in such a case? I mean, should you ignore those records or should you behave in a different way?

Comment: You seem to know that the array is zero-based, and since their are five items, this means the indices are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. 5 means the sixth row.

Comment: There are 6 fields in my post. Beryllium's way is working well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `filter()` in between:

```
val rdd = 
  sc.textFile("...").map(_.split("\t")).filter(_.size > 5).map(a => (a(0), a(5)))
```

Another option using `flatMap` (combined with extraction "on-the-fly"):

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("...").flatMap { l => 
  l.split("\t") match {
    case Array(x: String, _, _, _, _, y: String) => Some((x, y))
    case _ => None 
  }
}
```

The condition can be expressed with a *guard* as well (together with pattern matching on class `Array[String]`:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("...").flatMap { l => 
  l.split("\t") match {
    case a: Array[String] if a.size > 5 => Some((a(0), a(5)))
    // Only one column, provide a default for the other
    case a: Array[String] if a.size == 1 => Some((a(0), "default value"))
    // Ignore everything else
    case _ => None 
  }
}
```

In case of `flatMap` you can handle any number of non-matching lines as separate cases.